# entity framework and POCO entities, there is difference between EF versions?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.0, and to generate the POCO entities, first I create the edmx model, and from this model, I create my POCO entiies. However, I don't know if I this POCO entities are different if I generate them from EF 4.0 or EF 5... etc.

I ask this, because I am thinking in to use a repository that has an interface, and this interface can be implemented by many classes, one use EF 4.0, other EF 5 and other classes other technologies. I want to have this door open.

My doubt is how, from the client, say to the repository that I want add, modifiy or delete some register. If I create a POCO entities, I can create an external dll with this entities, that can be used my the different classes that implement the interface, but how I create this entities? from the edmx of EF 4.0, the edmx of EF 5, I create this manually (a lot of work if the dataBase is big)... etc?.

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POCO entities are not tied to a specific EF version. The reason for this is that these are just plain classes that do not have any EF related concepts. The side effect of this is that it should not matter how you create them - as long as they don't have any EF specific things they should work on EF 4, EF 5, with DbContext and ObjectContext.